# How do I deal with WS-Security when all I have is a wsdl?

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, ws-security, webservice-client, java-metro-framework

I'm trying to develop a stand-alone client app that uses web services in a Glassfish container (Metro). About all I have to work from is a wsdl for the wervices I'm trying to use. The wsdl is rife with all kinds of 'wsp:Policy' tags. Looks like IssuedToken, Trust13, ecryption are all utilized. 
So I generated some code from netbeans and JAX-WS. Everything went well, but when trying to run the client I get:
'WST0029:STS location could not be obtained from either IssuedToken or from client configuration for accessing the service http://localhost:8080/ ....'

That's when it occured to me that I know nothing about WSS. It doesn't look like any code was generated to deal with security. So, I'll have to go from scratch.
So where to start? Books? Tutorials?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Metro applies the policy in runtime from either the WSDL or the wsit-client.xml config file. That's why no code is generated related to policies. According to [this post](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/Can-I-load-WS-Policy-files-in-Java-instead-of-XML-td1065096.html#a1065101) it is not possible at the moment to do programatically.

[This tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/metro_usernametoken_profile) explains pretty well some of the things you can do with WSS, and though everything do probably not apply in this case it's still a good read.

The simplest way I've found of generating a client with WSS support is by using the `wsimport` script from Metro:

```
cd metro/bin/
mkdir src target
./wsimport.sh -s src -d target -extension -Xendorsed -verbose YourService.wsdl
```

Then install Metro into your application server (copy the libs to the correct places or run the ant script):

```
ant -f metro-on-glassfish.xml
```

Then put your local WSDL file in your classpath (e.g. your resource folder), so Metro can get it at runtime to apply the policies from your generated `YourService` class:

```
private final static URL YOURSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;

// This is enough, you don't need the wsdlLocation attribute 
// on the @WebServiceClient annotation if you have this.
static {
    YOURSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION =
        CustomerService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("YourService.wsdl");
}

public YourService() {
    super(YOURSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, 
            new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "YourService"));
}
```

And if you want [WS-Addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Addressing) you might need to add the feature manually to your binding method (Metro has never generated it for me, so I always have to add it myself).

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_IYourService")
public IYourService getWSHttpBindingIYourService() {
    WebServiceFeature wsAddressing = new AddressingFeature(true);

    IYourService service =
        super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Your",
                "WSHttpBinding_IYourService"), IYourService.class, 
                wsAddressing);

    return service;
}
```